# Calling 2D Array Function ''Cannot Convert Double[][] To Double" Error

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, arraylist, double

hope everyone is well.

I am getting this error when calling a method that I've created. I reason why I created the method is to return 2 double values, so I used a 2d array. Here is my relevant code:

```
Double[][] type2FS;
type2FS = new Double[rule.getRules().get(x).getAttributes().size()][rule.getRules().get(x).getAttributes().size()];
int pos=0;
```

the 2d array is the size of the number of attributes in a Decision Tree Rule, the rules are stored in an ArrayList.

```
type2FS[pos][pos]=calRight(grade.getDM(),grade.getDNU(),grade.getDNL(),Double.parseDouble(store.getData()[i][z]));
pos++;
break;
```

I get the error in the part after the '=' sign, with the message "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Double[][] to Double".
There are 4 double variables that are passed.

```
private Double[][] calRight(double dm, double dnu, double dnl, double value) 
    {
    double upperMg= (value-dnl) / (dnu-dnl);
    double lowerMg= 1 - upperMg;

    if(upperMg>1.0)
    {
        upperMg=1.0;    
    }
    else if (upperMg<0.0)
    {
        upperMg=0.0;
    }

    if(lowerMg>1.0)
    {
        lowerMg=1.0;
    }
    else if(lowerMg<0.0)
    {
        lowerMg=0.0;
    }
    Double[][] temp = {{upperMg},{lowerMg}};
    return temp;
}
```

This is the method that calculates the 2 double values that I wish to store in my type2FS 2D array.

The 2 double values that are returned from the function are part of a set. So one set looks like (4.5,5.5), now one decision tree rule can have many sets depending on the rule. So I thought the best way to store this was in a 2D Array.

I cant understand where I'am going wrong. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type2FS[pos][pos] = ...
```

is trying to assing a value to a single "cell" of your array, so it should be a double value. But you're passing an array instead.

So, change

```
type2FS[pos][pos]=calRight(grade.getDM(),grade.getDNU(),grade.getDNL(),Double.parseDouble(store.getData()[i][z]));
```

to

```
type2FS=calRight(grade.getDM(),grade.getDNU(),grade.getDNL(),Double.parseDouble(store.getData()[i][z]));
```

Anyway, "*[...] to return 2 double values, so I used a 2d array*" doesn't make sense, you could use a 1d array as well:

```
private Double[] calRight(double dm, double dnu, double dnl, double value) {
    //other code
    Double[] temp = {upperMg,lowerMg};
    return temp;
}
```

even though that's not the best solution anyway.

Comment: why would I use a 1D array ? If i wish to store 2 double values in array position 0, and then 2 more double values in position 1 etc ...

Comment: in your example `upperMg` and `lowerMg` are two primitive datatypes. Two primitive datatypes fits into a 1D array. If you want to save 2 double values + 2 double values, well... they are 4 double values, and they fits in a 1D array as well, even though you're free to use an array with 2 or more dimensions

Comment: okay @luigi I have changed it so that calRight returns a 1D array. However i get the same error on type2FS[pos] but when i delete [pos] it works, but i need pos in there as then it keeps overwriting the returned array from calRight in the same space in the type2FS array.

Comment: `type2FS` is a 2D array, you cannot assign a 1D array to a 2D array. By deleting one `[pos]` you actually assing 1D array to one "first grade" element of your 2D array (remember that a 2D array is an array made of many 1D arrays). Make `type2FS` a 1D array too

Comment: i have made 'type2FS' a 1D array. It is declared as 'Double[] type2FS;'
However when i call my calRight method, I do 'type2FS[pos]' but for some reason this a type mismatch error, and calRight is returning a 1D array now also, Double []. So I don't understand why its giving me this error, I just want to allocate the returned array from calRight into the type2FS array in position of pos.

Answer (score 1):

```
type2FS[pos][pos]=calRight(grade.getDM(),grade.getDNU(),grade.getDNL(),Double.parseDouble(store.getData()[i][z]));
```

It means i value is pos and j value is pos , then you are going to assign particular row and  and column value then its boolean.

instead of that

```
type2FS =calRight(grade.getDM(),grade.getDNU(),grade.getDNL(),Double.parseDouble(store.getData()[i][z]))
```

you can call like that.

type2FS[pos] is expecting one dimension array. Because you are mentioning only row.

type2FS[pos][[pos] is expecting Double value. Because you are mentioning row ans column.

Comment: ok @siva so now i want to return a 1D array, however i still get the error when I do type2FS[pos]. However when i delete [pos] its fine, but i need the pos variable so it doesnt keep overwriting in the same space as the area. I still get the type mismatch error.

Answer (score 1):

> Error - 'Cannot Convert Double[][] To Double"

yes it, why! `type2FS[pos][pos]` is double type reference & `calRight(...)` returns double[][]. It is type mismatch.

```
type2FS[pos][pos]=calRight(grade.getDM(),grade.getDNU(),grade.getDNL(),Double.parseDouble(store.getData()[i][z]));
```